# Mid() usage and for loops - Is this good practice?

Tags: vb.net

Ok so I was in college and I was talking to my teacher and he said my code isn't good practice. I'm a bit confused as to why so here's the situation. We basically created a for loop however he declared his for loop counter outside of the loop because it's considered good practice (to him) even though we never used the variable later on in the code so to me it looks like a waste of memory. We did more to the code then just use a message box but the idea was to get each character from a string and do something with it. He also used the Mid() function to retrieve the character in the string while I called the variable with the index. Here's an example of how he would write his code:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim justastring As String = "test"
For i = 1 To justastring.Length Then
    MsgBox( Mid( justastring, i, 1 ) )
End For
```

And here's an example of how I would write my code:

```
Dim justastring As String = "test"
For i = 0 To justastring.Length - 1 Then
    MsgBox( justastring(i) )
End For
```

Would anyone be able to provide the advantages and disadvantages of each method and why and whether or not I should continue how I am?

Comment: Personally, I like your version much more. But it's just personal preference. Btw. `Mid()` is a remainder of old VB6 and could be considered bad practice.

Comment: Except for the separate loop control variable declaration, this is going to be mostly a matter of opinion.  Personally, I'd lean more towards the shiny new NET string methods than the legacy VB functions

Comment: It seems you teacher is stuck with his old VB6 habits where you could not declare variables in the loops and could not access the chars from a string directly like you did in the bottom exemple. In the end it does not really matter much his style is just an "older" style. However i don't see why he says it's _bad practice_. And to had to what @NicoSchertler said `Mid`  _and_ `MsgBox` are old functions from VB6 that should not be used anymore.

Comment: The teacher's version is more old-school Basic.  We can't guess what he's trying to teach, do keep asking questions.

Comment: Probably better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, and I'll check out codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I only use strings.mid when I want to get a specific part of a string and even there I use strings.split. If you were to navigate in HTML and you want to get everything from one HTML tag to the end part of that tag. otherwise MID uses more cpu. If you run endless loop to check for speed you will see mid is slower tan accessing the char in a string straight from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be, to just use a `For Each` on the string.

Like this no index variable is needed.

```
Dim justastring As String = "test"
For Each c As Char In justastring
    MsgBox(c)
Next
```

Comment: Nice solution, one upped both of us haha. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it your way, because you could have variables hanging around consuming(albeit a small amount) of memory, but more importantly, It is better practice to define objects with as little scope as possible. In your teacher's code, the variable `i` is still accessible when the loop is finished. There are occasions when this is desirable, but normally, if you're only using a variable in a limited amount of code, then you should only declare it within the smallest block that it is needed.

As for your question about the  `Mid` function, individual characters as you know can be access simply by treating the string as an array of characters. After some basic benchmarking, using the `Mid` function takes a lot longer to process than just accessing the character by the index value. In relatively simple bits of code, this doesn't make much difference, but if you're doing it millions of times in a loop, it makes a huge difference.

There are other factors to consider. Such as code readability and modification of the code, but there are plenty of websites dealing with that sort of thing.

---

Finally I would suggest changing some compiler options in your visual studio

Option Strict to On

Option Infer to Off

Option Explicit to On

It means writing more code, but the code is safer and you'll make less mistakes. Have a look [here for an explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic--net-and-in-visual-b)

In your code, it would mean that you have to write

```
Dim justastring As String = "test"
For i As Integer = 0 To justastring.Length - 1 Then
    MsgBox( justastring(i) )
End For
```

This way, you know that `i` is definitely an integer. Consider the following ..

```
Dim i
```

Have you any idea what type it is? Me neither.

The compiler doesn't know what so it defines it as an object type which could hold anything. a string, an integer, a list..

Consider this code.

```
Dim i
Dim x
x = "ab"
For i = x To endcount - 1
    t = Mid(s, 999)
Next
```

The compiler will compile it, but when it is executed you'll get an SystemArgumenException. In this case it's easy to see what is wrong, but often it isn't. And numbers in strings can be a whole new can of worms.

Hope this helps.